# how can i add command to executable in linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, gaming

so i have installed my wolfenstein and when i start the executable i want to immediately join in the server.

in windows i did it in **properties** and after destination path i added

```
"/Desktop/etl.exe" +connect games.sk
```

how can i do that in linux (i have xubuntu 16.04 LTS) ?

i tried it in terminal like this

```
./etl +connect games.sk
```

but it didn't worked

Comment: If the executable doesn't support it then there is not much you can do.

Answer (score 1):

You didnt mention which *exact* version of Wolfenstein you have.  This would be a major help.

You need to check the documentation of *your* Wolfenstein game to see which command line arguments are accepted - if any - and how to properly use them.  Windows and Linux operating systems handle com do command line switches differently from each other.  And there is no guarantee that the switches for the same game are implemented the same way on different operating systems.

Comment: well i use newest ET Legacy, i know it works for it my dad used to had it like that but i cant seem to make it work. he made some script that when he launched the game he immiaetly connected to that gameserver unfortunetly i cant connect him rn